# Minecraft-Command to remove all dropped sandstone

Tags: minecraft-commands

As the title says. I am getting a lot of dropped sandstone that I would like to get killed, but I also have bamboo and minecarts that I don't want getting deleted. Is there any way to do this using command blocks? The /fill command will not work for me, as I need dropped items killed, not placed items.

Answer (score 1):

As @infek said, `/kill @e[type=item]` is a good option. However, you need to specify nbt in order to kill only sandstone: `/kill @e[type=minecraft:item,nbt={Item:{id:"minecraft:sandstone"}}]`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried /kill @e[type=item]? This will destroy all dropped items though so keep that in mind.

Comment: This doesn't quite work for me, it also destroys the dropped bamboo.

Comment: Yes, that's why I said it destroys all dropped items. The command does work so I don't know what you're talking about